# How do I replace a video on YouTube and keep the same URL?

Tags: youtube, video

I want to replace it with a version that has better quality. I do not care about the  view count, comments or ratings.

Answer (score 5):

> Unfortunately, you won't be able to replace an old video with a new one and keep the original view count, comments or ratings. Instead, you may want to try using annotations or link to the new version of the video from your old video.

Source: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/58101

Comment: I don't care about losing the view count or comments, thats irrelevant for me! I just want to upload the same video with a higher quality. Is that possible? (all answers regarding this question before has always forcused on view count and comments, thats totally irrelevant for me, I just want to keep the same url!) Possible?

Comment: don´t mind the view count and stuff, for me it´s pretty clear that it´s not possible from that text. you can also read this in several help sections if you do a google search - it´s also in the answer of that other thread.